# How to retrieve hierarchical data from SQL table

Tags: sql, hierarchy

I have 2 tables : T_Employees and T_Projects

Every project has different number of employees assigned. What i need to do, is to get hierarchical structure of each employee, assigned to a specific project.

Look at the image below and the expected results.

How to get this done on Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2?

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Projects](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Projects] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_Projects] ON
INSERT [dbo].[T_Projects] ([ID], [ProjectId], [EmployeeId]) VALUES (1, 456,10)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Projects] ([ID], [ProjectId], [EmployeeId]) VALUES (2, 456, 12)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Projects] ([ID], [ProjectId], [EmployeeId]) VALUES (3, 23, 11)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_Projects] OFF

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Employees](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Level] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Employee] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Department] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [MasterId] [int] NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ON
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (1, 1, N'Thomas S.', N'A', NULL, N'1-4', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (2, 1, N'Michael F.', N'A', NULL, N'1-5', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (3, 1, N'Simone S.', N'A', NULL, N'1-3', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (4, 2, N'Stefan K.', N'B', 1, N'2-18', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (5, 2, N'Mike T.', N'B', 2, N'2-96', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (6, 2, N'Loris P.', N'B', 3, N'2-15', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (7, 3, N'Lennon I.', N'B', 4, N'2-19', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (8, 3, N'Kerim K.', N'C', 4, N'2-66', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (9, 3, N'Ilmas Y.', N'C', 6, N'2-59', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (10, 4, N'Innes Y.', N'D', 8, N'3-89', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (11, 4, N'Andreas U.', N'E', 7, N'3-63', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] ([ID], [Level], [Employee], [Department], [MasterId], [Code], [Note]) VALUES (12, 4, N'Fatih O.', N'I', 9, N'3-32', NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_Employees] OFF
```

Comment: Please do **not** add sample data as pictures! Best is a simplified test scenario (`DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 ...); INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(...)`or a working [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com). Nobody wants to type your data in, just to create a test scenario...

Comment: And please add what you've tried so far and tag your RDBMS (vendor and version)

Comment: What is the relation between those two tables?

Comment: Are the two tables even related?

Comment: @Shnugo i will create the simple script to create tables and data ASAP

Comment: T_Employees.Id = Projects.EmployeId

Comment: A test scenario for DB tables and content is attached

Comment: Thx for the test scenarion, great! The question's upvote is mine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can travers a hierarchy with a recursive CTE

This is the classical top down CTE:

```
WITH EmployeesHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT ID,[Level],Employee,Department,Code,MasterId
    FROM T_Employees
    WHERE [Level]=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nextLevel.ID,nextLevel.[Level],nextLevel.Employee,nextLevel.Department,nextLevel.Code,nextLevel.MasterId
    FROM EmployeesHierarchy AS recCall
    INNER JOIN T_Employees AS nextLevel ON nextLevel.[Level]=recCall.[Level]+1 AND nextLevel.MasterId=recCall.ID
)
SELECT * FROM EmployeesHierarchy
ORDER BY [Level],MasterId
GO
```

And now the other way round: I start with the employees mentioned in the project and move up the list until there is no parentId any more. The Project's data gotten in the first part of the CTE are just passed through to show up in all rows.

```
WITH EmployeesHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT p.ID AS p_ID,p.ProjectId,e.ID AS e_ID,[Level],e.Employee,e.Department,e.Code,e.MasterId
    FROM T_Projects AS p 
        INNER JOIN T_Employees AS e ON p.EmployeeId=e.ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT recCall.p_ID,recCall.ProjectId,nextLevel.ID,nextLevel.[Level],nextLevel.Employee,nextLevel.Department,nextLevel.Code,nextLevel.MasterId
    FROM EmployeesHierarchy AS recCall
    INNER JOIN T_Employees AS nextLevel ON nextLevel.ID=recCall.MasterId
)
SELECT * FROM EmployeesHierarchy
--WHERE ProjectId=456
ORDER BY [Level]
```

The result

```
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| p_ID | ProjectId | e_ID | Level | Employee   | Department | Code | MasterId |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 3    | 23        | 1    | 1     | Thomas S.  | A          | 1-4  | NULL     |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 2    | 456       | 3    | 1     | Simone S.  | A          | 1-3  | NULL     |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 1    | 456       | 1    | 1     | Thomas S.  | A          | 1-4  | NULL     |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 2    | 456       | 6    | 2     | Loris P.   | B          | 2-15 | 3        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 1    | 456       | 4    | 2     | Stefan K.  | B          | 2-18 | 1        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 3    | 23        | 4    | 2     | Stefan K.  | B          | 2-18 | 1        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 3    | 23        | 7    | 3     | Lennon I.  | B          | 2-19 | 4        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 1    | 456       | 8    | 3     | Kerim K.   | C          | 2-66 | 4        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 2    | 456       | 9    | 3     | Ilmas Y.   | C          | 2-59 | 6        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 1    | 456       | 10   | 4     | Innes Y.   | D          | 3-89 | 8        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 2    | 456       | 12   | 4     | Fatih O.   | I          | 3-32 | 9        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| 3    | 23        | 11   | 4     | Andreas U. | E          | 3-63 | 7        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+------------+------------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result datasets can be get running this query:

```
declare @project int ;
declare cur_project cursor for 
select distinct ProjectId from T_Projects;

open cur_project
fetch next from cur_project into @project
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
select E.* from [dbo].[T_Projects] P
inner join [dbo].[T_Employees] E
on P.EmployeeId = E.ID
where P.ProjectId = @project

fetch next from cur_project into @project
end
close cur_project;
deallocate cur_project;
```

Comment: Your query may be right, but this is not what it should...The focus is not to get both data sets for every Project.
I need one data set, based on the project id (For example, project id 456).  The query should return the users with the id 10 and 12, which are assigned to the project, but also the other hierarchical data for that users (superior employees, until top level). Take a look for example at the first table - the image shows the result set how it should look like.

Comment: Try to avoid `CURSOR` and `WHILE`! There are very rare situations where there is no other chance, but - if ever possible - a set based approach will be better than a RBAR row based one.

Comment: Initially I misunderstood the problem. Later I started working on this again. @Shnugo I agree, I am not a fan of CURSOR either, they are costly. I loved your answer by the way. Recursive CTE is the answer to this.Pretty straightforward. I was struggling with this. Somehow, recursive CTE didn't cross my mind. Thanks!!

Comment: @AkankshaSingh I love Stack Overflow especially for this: You place an answer, some else places a better one and you *learn*. That is the main reason for being here :-) Thx and Happy Coding